# json_to_record with embedded encoded json in PostgreSQL >= 10

Tags: json, postgresql

With PostgreSQL 9.6, it's possible to convert JSON embedded as a string within JSON as follows:

```
# select * from json_to_record('{"key":"{\"embedded\": 42}"}') as x(key json);
       key        
------------------
 {"embedded": 42}
(1 row)
```

This fails with PostgreSQL 10 and above:

```
# select * from json_to_record('{"key":"{\"embedded\": 42}"}') as x(key json);
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Token "embedded" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: "{"embedded...
```

The [PostgreSQL 10 release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/release-10.html#id-1.11.6.13.5) mention changes to `populate_json` and related functions (including, presumable `json_to_record`), apparently to deal with non-quoted embedded JSON:

> With this change, array-type fields in the destination SQL type are properly converted from JSON arrays, and composite-type fields are properly converted from JSON objects. Previously, such cases would fail because the text representation of the JSON value would be fed to array_in() or record_in(), and its syntax would not match what those input functions expect.

It seems the error when used with quoted JSON is an accidental side-effect of this change. Is there a way achieve the 9.6 behavior with the newer versions?

Answer (score 2):

You can first get the column as `text` and then cast it to `json`.

```
SELECT x.key::json
       FROM json_to_record('{"key":"{\"embedded\": 42}"}') x(key text);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=1fd8fbaa7ca56a952375f61638de8eb3)